# Heroku can't find ssh key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

I'm currently wrapping up the railbridge installfest.

I'm at this point: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_heroku_account

My last issue, I've not had any luck sorting out is get heroku doesn't recognize my SSH keys. I've included the following from the terminal to show me trying to add the key, confirm the SSH files are where they're supposed to be, as well as how Heroku responds. Thanks for any help.

keith@HAL:~$ heroku keys:add

Could not find an existing SSH key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
? Would you like to generate a new one? Yes
 ▸    EACCES: spawn EACCES

keith@HAL:~$ heroku version

heroku-cli/6.12.7 (linux-x64) node-v7.10.0

keith@HAL:~$ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa

/home/keith/.ssh/id_rsa

keith@HAL:~$ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

/home/keith/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keith@HAL:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Identity added: /home/keith/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/keith/.ssh/id_rsa)

keith@HAL:~$ heroku keys:add

Could not find an existing SSH key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

? Would you like to generate a new one? (Y/n) 
keith@HAL:~$